# How to list the index and columns names together for a given dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, indexing

How to list the column names along with their index from a data frame in python ?

the below code gives only the index numbers of the column names. But i need to learn on how to list the index numbers along with the column names for a large dataset with multiple columns names.

```
enter code here:

columnnames=['a','b','c']
df.columns.get_loc(col) for col in  column_names
```

Comment: Use this: `[df.columns.get_loc(c) for c in df.columns]`

Comment: I did the same , but i could get only the index  .I am looking for something that shows column names along with their index

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html
Try Loc

Comment: @SaiSrija Check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `map` like this:

```
In [3359]: col_map = {df.columns.get_loc(c):c  for c in df.columns}

In [3360]: col_map
Out[3360]: {0: 'id', 1: 'count', 2: 'colors'}
```